# Wigner's friend question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, thought-experiment, quantum-measurements

This is probably a dumb question, but does anyone know whether both Wigner and Wigner's friend observe the same result once both have been in the room and measured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they should observe the same result (although what exactly this means might depend on which interpretation you work in).